# Error message: "Windows cannot be installed to this disk..."

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, reinstall

I am trying to install Windows 7 64-bit. My primary harddrive is an SSD. The Windows installer informed me that:

> On EFI systems, Windows can only be installed to GPT disks.

So, after a lot of research, I was able to convert the SSD from MBR to GPT! :)

However, now I get the following message:

> Windows cannot be installed to this disk, the selected disk is of the GPT partition style.

What went wrong? How can I install Windows 7 to my SSD?

Comment: WHY ARE WE SHOUTING?!  Also, can you please specify the motherboard in question?  Probably this is a UEFI/BIOS setting (the installer acts differently depending on what mode it's in) that needs to be changed, but it's hard to say specifically how to approach it without knowing the hardware in question.

Comment: I want to up vote this just for the lousy Microsoft mixed messages. He is yelling because he is totally frustrated at the inept, uninformative messages he is receiving from the Windows installer routine, which sucks by the way, Microsoft should include a crystal Ball with each copy of Windows, and I am a dyed in the wool Windows guy, but my God, sometimes I just want to SCREAM! when using Windows.

Answer (score 1):

"windows cannot be installed to disk 0 
partition 2. (show details)", when I click show details I get the 
message, "windows cannot be installed on this disk. The selected disk is
of the GPT partition style."

It's the error that you can maybe see when you try to install new Windows on your computer.
Be aware that whatever is in your hard drive will be gone forever, including partitions and operating system.
Now I will show you 2 methods to resolve your problem :

Method #1:

1. Boot up to installation DVD/CD.
2. Click install but don't follow through.
3. Press SHIFT-F10 to bring up console.
4. Type "diskpart"
5. Once inside diskpart type:
    -> list disk (find the one you want to convert)
    -> select disk 0 (select the one you want from the list)
    -> convert mbr (should take a second or two)
    -> quit
6. Continue with install

Method #2:

1. Boot up to installation DVD/CD.
2. Click install but don't follow through.
3. Press SHIFT-F10 to bring up console.
4. Type "diskpart"
5. Once inside diskpart type:
     -> list disk (find the one you want to convert)
     -> select disk 0 (select the one you want from the list)
     -> clean (wait an hour or so until its done)
     -> quit
6. Continue with install

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Set the disk access mode in BIOS to AHCI instead of SATA.

http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/35448-63-windows-installed-disk